# Is there a name for this type of security window?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, vocabulary

Armories are often depicted with a security window screened by mesh, with a cutout opening for the guard/staff to pass weapons and ammunition through.

Are there any terms for this setup more proper than "window", "mesh", and "cutout"? Pharmacies and banks often have similar setups, using glass instead of mesh, but again I can't think of any term more appropriate than "window".

[image: Armory guard behind security mesh]

Answer (score 1):

Metal lattices are [grilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grille). Often used for the purpose of light-weight security, also for [car ventilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grille_(car)) and [decorative pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grillwork).

The opening itself is an [access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control) feature, of which there are many types. Yours is called a **security hatch** (as in loft hatch).

Comment: I don't think that "mesh" is any less appropriate of a term than grill, and the type of metal grid seen in the image is often sold as "security mesh". In particular, I'm wondering if there is any terminology more specific to this exact type of setup, where there is a window covered by a barrier of mesh with a cutout to pass items through.

Comment: remembered it! it's a hatch